# Isn't the tag feature-request too broad or ambiguous?

Tags: discussion, meta, ambiguous-tags

The description of feature-request tag:

> This tag is for proposals of new features on the site, or requests for
>   a change to an existing feature.

But aren't new features and change-requests two very different things?

The first will open a discussion on something that is actually missing on the site while the other while bring experience and case of something that people want made in a different way.

EDIT:

- change request is something that can be asked mostly because it does not meet the expectation even if the function is perfectly done by requirements. This means it could be a change in the needs of people so I would say it is EVOLVING
- a new feature is just something missing. os it may have never been there in the first place so I would say it is IMPROVING

So separation is good because improvement should be discussed and a lot while evolvment should be a necessity and if does not happen it becomes a bug and so it should not be discussed but aknowledged, that makes it thousand times more important than improvement and therefore having it separated can only make good to anyone including the website

Comment: So how will meta be better off by separating these two concepts into different tags?

Comment: Isn't a bug report also a "change request"? "enhancement" might be a better word than "feature", but one could also argue that fixing a bug is an enhancement (although if anyone tried to make that argument in *my* bug tracker I might have to smack them...)

Comment: but why a discussion needs to be downvoted so much? isn't the downvote used for low quality rather than disagreement?

Comment: See the [meta-faq#vote-differences]; votes on MSO are different from the regular Stack Exchange websites.

Comment: @MaurizioIndenmark This is a very low quality request in that you haven't given a reason for why we should want to make this type of change.  Even upon being asked what benefit it would have, you have yet to provide *any* reason.  It would be a considerable amount of work, and thus to justify that work it would need to provide a considerable benefit.  When making a proposal you should not just state what you are proposing, but also the problem you're trying to solve, how the site is improved, possible drawbacks, etc.  Disagreement aside, this is low quality post, and the votes reflect that.

Comment: so are you saying that downvotes are because this is a low quality question or becuase people don't want this changed?

Comment: @MaurizioIndenmark I'm saying that it's a combination of both.  It's a low quality question suggesting a change that people don't want to see.

Comment: well if downvotes means both for all you senior user and even moderators, I really think then it is not very clear anywhere how this downvote system works here. and this prove my point again. ;P http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221814/downvotes-used-as-a-disagreement-is-it-enough

Comment: You have of course read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta right? Especially the section on voting? It's the least we can expect from a user. If you have, and find it unclear, suggestions for improvement are always welcome. But as always, make sure you research if such suggestions have been made before.

Comment: @Bart Exactly because I read it and I know that in fact people donøt use the downvoting that way. Look at this question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221805/shouldnt-an-answer-accepted-during-a-bounty-be-awarded-the-bounty it shows how the downvotes have not be used for agreement but because the question was a duplicate. And this is a case when instead it is used as a disagreement but it should not have: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221810/isnt-the-tag-feature-request-too-broad-or-ambiguous  And all this in a matter of few hours.

Comment: @Servy please read the edit to see why I think this is good for meta-stack

Comment: @MaurizioIndenmark To the first point, I have seen no evidence of being confused as to how to post their questions.  You'll need to provide evidence that there is confusion being caused as a result of the current tagging methods.  To the second point, you thinking that it's an improvement doesn't tell us anything.  Explain *why* it's an improvement, don't just say *that* it's an improvement.

Comment: I think you misunderstodd what I wrote. a new feature is an improvement and a change is an evolvment. This is to explain why they should be separated. And sorry I forgot to say why the separation is good.

Comment: @MaurizioIndenmark And why does this *matter*?  How is the site better off as a result of this change.  You *still* haven't answered that.  It's an irrelevant distinction and combining these ideas in one tag causes no problems.  The distinction is arbitrary and has no real effect on how the questions should be addressed, posted, reviewed, or searched for.

Comment: @MaurizioIndenmark I find it difficult to see what you're getting at. Are there perhaps specific existing Meta posts you have in mind which explicitly fall in one category or another. Maybe such an illustration would help (me at least) to understand what you're trying to say.

Comment: brb, finding the picture of a bunch of pencils all evenly lined up side by side except for one that's slightly off...

Answer (score 3):

> Isn't the tag feature-request too broad or ambiguous?

No, it's not too broad or ambiguous. It's just fine.

Right now Meta tagging system is simple, in its base: each question must be one of four things: bug report, feature request (which can also ask to change existing feature), discussion or support.

Starting to add sub-tags will only complicate things and make it harder for users, especially new users, to choose correct tag.

Comment: I agree if only those four cases are allowed.

Comment: but why a discussion needs to be downvoted so much? isn't the downvote used for low quality rather than disagreement?

Comment: @MaurizioIndenmark you stumbled on the "dark side of Meta" as I personally call it, downvotes mean, in essence, disagreement. People disagree with the idea of separating the tag hence downvoting. Not very friendly or constructive in first look, that's just how this place works.